# GA4 Events from GTM Not Showing Up in Events List

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, conversion-tracking

I've read a few questions on this but nothing seems to have worked for me, I'd be grateful for any help.

Basically, events appear in the debug ribbon while in preview mode on GTM and I can see the debug parameter = 1. When not in GTM preview mode and on the site normally, the events increase under 'top events' to the right of the debug ribbon, but don't appear in the ribbon itself.

[image: GA4 Debug Page]

At no point are these 'ug_apply_click' events available on the main events list to mark as conversions.

I've checked the GTM container is published, with events set up correctly and it's been a couple of weeks now.

I've tried changing the reporting identity from blended to observed.

I'm sure there are enough events happening for them to appear, as far as I can tell I've set this up exactly the same on other sites and it's worked fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Tom

Comment: What ribbon are you talking about? Show some screenshots laying out your problem. Try using adswerve's datalayer debugger extension in production and see the events in the console.

Comment: I mean the live list of events on the debug page, I've added a screenshot to the original post for clarity.

Comment: don't use that debug page. It's buggy. Either use the Network tab or the Adswerve's debugger.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll check it out, but that's not really the issue, the issue is that these aren't coming through to the events page to be marked as conversions, this debug page is just to show they're being received...

Comment: Ah, I see. I got confused there. Ok, why do you expect a new event to appear in the main conversion list? Do you see a CTA there saying New Conversion Event? Add your event there and then you'll be able to mark it as a conversion. Maybe it's a little awkward design.

Comment: Hmm, when I add it manually it's there but no data is coming up against it, it's like it's not recognised as the same thing...

Comment: can you see your event when using the Explore view?